# Formatting ToShortDateString to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have Calendar like this one:

**View**

```
 <td>
     <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
      OnSelectionChanged="DateChange">
     </asp:Calendar>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
```

**.Cs file**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()+'.';
    }

    protected void DateChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() + '.';
    }
```

It display date as `"MM/dd/yyyy"`, but I want to display it as `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, I try it changing `DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()+'.';`   to `DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

but I get

> Error 3   No overload for method 'ToShortDateString' takes 1 arguments

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[`ToShortDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring) does *not* have an overload which takes any parameter.

If your `ToShortDateString()` returns `MM/dd/yyyy` format, that means your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) has this format in it's [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) property.

You can always use [custom formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for that like with *proper* culture like;

```
TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Do you need the second parameter? It looks like that's only necessary for the built-in formats: `"d", "D", "f", "F", "g", "G", "m", "o", "r", "s", "t", "T", "u", "U", "Y"`

Comment: @Sinjai As a best practise, yes, you need it. Otherwise, you _might_ get different formatted results. The `/` specifier (for `DateSeparator`) and `:` specifier (for `TimeSeparator`) has a "special" meanings as _replace me current culture or supplied culture date or time separator_ in custom date and time formats. If you don't supply _any_ culture with those specifiers, they are replaced with `CurrentCulture`'s date and/or time seperator which _might_ be different from `/` or `:` for different cultures.

Comment: Is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture really necessary?

Comment: @AlexanderS.In that case, yes. See my previous comment. `/` and `:` characters has a special meaning which their "representations" depends on what culture setting you use.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be simpler to use:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```